# initializing a 100 point array

Tags: arrays, c++-cli, managed

quote from other post:

Call `Graphics.FillPolygon()`. You will need a brush rather than a pen and you must put     your points into a point `array Point[].`

The sample code from MSDN is like this:

```
// Create solid brush.
SolidBrush^ blueBrush = gcnew SolidBrush( Color::Blue );  

// Create points that define polygon.  
Point point1 = Point(50,50);  
Point point2 = Point(100,25);  
Point point3 = Point(200,5);       
Point point4 = Point(250,50);  
Point point5 = Point(300,100);  
Point point6 = Point(350,200);  
Point point7 = Point(250,250);  
array<Point>^ curvePoints = {point1,point2,point3,point4,point5,point6,point7};
```

This is awful! I have to put in a hundred equidistant points!

Draw polygon to screen.

```
e->Graphics->FillPolygon( blueBrush, curvePoints );
```

I have tried many things:

```
array<Point,2>^ aPoints;
//Points tabPoints[10][10];//= new Points[10][10];
Points = gcnew array<Point,2>(10,10);
//init des tableaux 

for (int i = 0;i<10;i++)
{
    for(int j =0;j<10;j++)
    {
    //tabPoints[i][j].pX =i*10;
    //tabPoints[i][j].pY = j * 10;
    // = new Points(i*10,j*10);
    aPoints[i,j]= new Point(i*20,j*20);
    }
}
```

None of them work!

Comment: And the question is? ...

Comment: _Really ?_  How do I create a 100 point array in C++/CLI ?

Comment: Get rid of `new` inside the loop.  You want a `Point` value, not a pointer to one.  (MSDN had that part right)

Comment: Oh, and show your error messages, don't just say "none of it works".

Comment: @BenVoigt Please post that as an answer so he can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @David: Done.  Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2-D array isn't necessarily what you want, but you can make your current code work with just one minor change:

- Get rid of `new` inside the loop. You want a `Point` value, not a pointer to one.

MSDN had that part right already.

Answer (score 1):

What you've got now isn't a 100 point array, it's a 10x10 2D array. Try `gcnew array<Point>(100)`, and you'll be able to pass that to FillPolygon.

Comment: @Ben Voigt 's answer was the right one, thanks. It turned out I needn't FillPolygon after all; a 2d array does just fine, with fillEllipse for every point in the array. I am still learning how to get around in this forum: how do I mark his answer as the right one ?

Comment: He didn't post an answer, he posted a comment. The convention seems to be to ask him to post it as an answer, which I've just done.